# Android Studio Endpoints and peer not authenticated error in gradle build

Tags: android, maven, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to create an cloud endpoints module in android studio but after going through the wizard, it creates the module but gradle build fails giving:

`Error:Cause: peer not authenticated`

How can I resolve this error?
And sometimes, I don't know how but this error is resolved on its own, then another error pops up after gradle build failure, which says.

`"Unknown Host: repo1.maven.org"`

How to resolve both these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Given that it only happens sometimes, and the fact that you are seeing errors - even once the first part works - that say `Unknown host`, I suspect the lines before `Error:Cause: peer not authenticated` (if you check them) are letting you know a connection timed out, there was a "could not resolve" on some auth domain it was trying to reach, a "could not GET", etc... basically a network problem, possibly related to your network speed but also could be just a problem with your DNS server.

What DNS server are you reaching, and can you try to ping it? If it sometimes responds slow, or if you can show a failed ping to your DNS server during a timeframe when these bugs are occurring, you have found the source of the problem.